# Perform Action When Button Is Held And Another Action When Button Is Released

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-10-iot-core

I am using visual studios to create a Windows IoT app. On the GUI of the app there is a button that when held down with a mouse click or a key being pressed it performs an action, in this case a text box changes its text and a motor is run.  When the button is released the text box changes its text and the motor is stopped.

I created a button in the .xml file and button_holding event in the .cs, but this doesn't perform any of the actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the GUI of the app there is a button that when held down with a
>   mouse click or a key being pressed it performs an action, in this case
>   a text box changes its text and a motor is run. When the button is
>   released the text box changes its text and the motor is stopped.

You can use PointerPressedEvent and PointerReleasedEvent to achieve it. This is the code works for me:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    myButton.AddHandler(PointerPressedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(myButton_PointerPressed), true);
    myButton.AddHandler(PointerReleasedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(myButton_PointerReleased), true);
}

private void myButton_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myText.Text = "Running...";
}

private void myButton_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myText.Text = "Stopped";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Holding event to get similar MouseUp and MouseDown in traditional WinForms, like so

```
private void Button_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.HoldingState == Windows.UI.Input.HoldingState.Started)
            {
                //do things when button on hold
            }
            else if (e.HoldingState == Windows.UI.Input.HoldingState.Completed ||
                e.HoldingState == Windows.UI.Input.HoldingState.Canceled)
            {
                //do things when button release
            }
        }
```